# Height percentage css not working bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I´m trying to make responsive columns, they must have the 40% height of their parent div. But it doesn´t work.

This is my HTML:

```
            <div class="row brands">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 brand-container">

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 brand-container">

                </div>
            </div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.brands {
   background-color: green;
   min-height: 100%;
}

.brand-container {
  background-color: red;
  height: 40%; 
}
```

When I run the web on my PC it works perfect, but it doesn´t work on my phone.

I´m working with Bootstrap.

I have changed the vh value to %, but it doesn´t work yet.

Comment: Probably because of `vh`. That can cause issues on iOS devices [(article)](https://gist.github.com/pburtchaell/e702f441ba9b3f76f587). Which type of phone do you use?

Comment: An Android, Lg L Bello, I run the web with the emulator of Chrome and it works fine, but I would like that the web run on all devices.

Comment: Well then you need a fallback for devices that don’t support the `vh` unit yet.

Comment: What is above the row in your code: body tag?

Comment: No, I have a lot divs, 

        <div class="main-body">
                <div class="brand-title">
                    Brands
                </div>
                <div class="row brands">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 brand-container">
kljkljlkjl
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 brand-container">
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>

This is "the body", before I have the navbar, and all this inside a div called "display".

Answer (score 1):

Well It is possible, that It is caused because of the vh value. Some versions of mobile browsers does not support it. Look here:

> http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: My phone supports vh value, I was working with other divs. Anyway, I will remove this property.